# create welcome screen for android app using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I want to show a welcome screen as well as some basic tutorials of my app during the FIRST TIME user open the app, and do not show it anymore later on. The welcome screen is likely to contain several pages and users need to swipe from one to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is Phonegap a hard requirement? You could do this very easily using SharedPreferences. Just before the launch of the welcome screen, check if a preference like ShownWelcomeScreen has been set. If it's false, display the screen, and at the end set it to true. If it's already true, simply launch the other port of your Activity.